# What is fast DB design for this scenario?

Tags: database-design

I have table `Product` has a many-to-many relation with table `unit`, but `product` must have at least one basic `unit` so there are two solutions:

**Solution 1**:

Add `[UnitID]` in `product` table and then create new table `Product_Unit` for many-to-many relation

- `Product: id, name, unitID, sell_price, Buy_price`
- `Unit: id, name`
- `Product_unit: productID, UnitID, sell_price, Buy_price`

**Solution 2**:

Create only table `Product_Unit` for many to many relation and add specific column to flag one record as basic record

- `Product: id, name`
- `Unit: id, name`
- `Product_unit: productID, UnitID, sell_price, Buy_price, Essential_unit_Flag`

Comment: definetely solution 2. It may seem a bit more complicated for some queries... but Solution 1 is a nightmare for a lot of them, and for maintenance too.

Comment: so i need to treat logically the product table and it's basic record unit as one entity in my code -- code will be nightmare =D

Comment: you can use a VIEW that combines the basic record unit with its matching product record... and your code will never know the difference ;)